# ListView builds all items when inside another scrollable widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to have a `ListView.builder` widget inside another scrollable widget, but when I build a tree like that, the inner `ListView.builder` builds all items (so the rendering is slow with huge lists)

I have the following build method :

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(""),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              itemCount: 999,
              itemBuilder: (_, position) {
                if (position == 998)
                  {/* breakpoint*/}
                return Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 100,);
              }
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The execution always stopped in the breakpoint in the `itemBuilder`
(but if I remove the first `SingleChildScrollView` and the `Column`, everything is okay, the last items are rendered only when *needed*)

Comment: use `CustomScrollView` in that case, or build all of your widgets (including leading `Text`) inside `ListView.builder`

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. `SingleChildScrollView` lets its children get as much space as they need and scrolls them. `ListView` uses this as an opportunity to render everything. `SingleChildScrollView` scrolls this huge `ListView`. `ListView` needs some kind of size constraint to render only the items it shows. Right now it thinks it's showing all of them.